# How do I properly import an fbx 3D model into Unity3D?

Tags: unity, models, fbx

I am trying to properly import a 3D model that was made for my game in Unity3D. I was able to import the model, and I put the texture on it, but there are several other files that go unused. I think I'm not importing the files properly, or I'm not using the files properly.

The files provided for me are as followed: ([You can see these in this link as well](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_HWNOHDd8mYNmgtNnlSb1dXTFk&usp=sharing))

- Cheese.FBX
- Cheese.obj
- Cheese.png
- Cheese_D.png (What does the "_D" indicate?)
- Cheese_N.png (What does the "_N" indicate?)

Perhaps I am overthinking it, but i feel like I should be attaching cheese_d and cheese_n to the prefab I'm making somehow, but I don't understand their function. I am fairly new to 3D modeling, so I think I'm missing some conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need .obj if you want to use .fbx.

_D usually indicates a diffuse texture, _N is a normal map. You must create a new material and assign those textures into it.

Comment: Okay, I thought I needed to do something like that. But, I wasn't able to put more than one texture on the model. Every time I put another one on it, it just replaced the old one.

Comment: When you create the material in Unity, use a shader that has both diffuse and normal map slots.

Comment: Thank you! I used what you told me along with http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-bumpmap.html to get this working. It looks so much better now.